# How to reduce this Riccati ODE to a $1^{st}$ order linear ODE: $y'=1+x-(1+2x)y+xy^2$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this differential equation:

$$ y'=1+x-(1+2x)y+xy^2 \quad (E_y)$$

that has a given partial solution $y_1(x)=1$

---

This equation is apparently Riccati form. The theory states that the following substitution will reduce the ODE to a linear first order form:

$$(y(x)\neq 1): u(x) = \frac{1}{y(x)-y_1(x)} = \frac{1}{y(x)-1} \iff $$

$$ \bbox[15px,#ffd,border:1px solid blue]{y(x)=1 + \frac{1}{u(x)} \quad(1)} \quad \bbox[15px,#ffd,border:1px solid blue]{\text{and}\quad  y'(x) =-\frac{u'(x)}{u^2(x)} \quad (2)}$$

Hence, plugging $(1),(2)$ in $(E_y)$:

$$ u'(x) = u^2(x)(2+x)+u(x)(2x+1)-x \quad (E_u)$$

---

Apparently, the substitution didn't change the form of the differential equation. We notice that $(E_u)$ is still Riccati form.

Why did this happen and what is a proper way to solve this?

Comment: $y'=-u'/u^2$, not $+u'/u^2$.

Comment: @user10354138 indeed, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y'=1+x-(1+2x)y+xy^2$$
$$y'=1-y+x(y-1)^2$$
This is Bernoulli's differential equation

Substitute $z=y-1$:
$$z'=-z+xz^2$$
it's easy to transform this DE to a linear first order DE just substitute $u=\dfrac 1z$.
$$u'=u-x$$

Comment: Good approach. But without the substitution $z=y-1$ its a Riccati, innit?

Comment: Yes it's Riccati's equation @Veriun

Comment: The problem with my solution is that $E_u$ is wrong. If substitutions are made correctly and carefully, the Ricatti methodology is fine. But I like your approach too, thus I am accepting your answer.

Comment: Thanls. Yes your approach is good too. From Riccati DE you get via a certain substitution a Bernouilli's equation then you transform again to get a first order linear DE @Veriun

Answer (score 1):

$$y'=1+x-(1+2x)y+xy^2~~~(1)$$
One solution of this is $y(x)=1.$
Let the other solution be
$$y=1+\frac{1}{u(x)}$$
Let us put it in (1), we get
$$u'(x)-u(x)=-x \implies  \frac{d}{dx}ue^{-x}=-xe^{-x}\implies u=-e^{x}\int xe^{-x} dx+Ce^{x}$$
$$\implies u(x)=(1+x)+ce^{x}$$
So the second solution of (1) is
$$y_2(x)=1+\frac{1}{1+x+Ce^{x}}$$